# SQL search #hashtag from posts

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to search hastag from posts but they are in post_text column

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_text = #hashtag
```

post tex column content example:

**text here #hashtag text here**

I have a hashtag page to get clicked hastag via get, but How can I do it because hashtag is inside text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `like` in the `where` clause:

```
where post_text like concat('%', ?, '%')
```

The `?` is a placeholder for a parameter passed into the query.

If you just want one value in particular:

```
where post_text like '%#hashtag%'
```

Comment: Thanks, let me see how it works.

Comment: Solved, thank you!